# Call returning Future<Void> throws NPE in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, future

I'm trying to unit test some of my client code that looks like the following:

```
@Override
public void stop() {

    if (client != null) {
        Future<Void> disconnectClient = client.disconnect();

        try {
            disconnectClient.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.info("Failed to disconnect client: ", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    } else {
        logger.error("Client does not exist.");
    }
}
```

where the `disconnect()` returns a `Future<Void>`.  A simple test looks like:

```
@Mock
private MyClient client;

@InjectMocks
private MyServer objectUnderTest = new MyServer();

@Test
public void shouldCallDisconnectOnClientWhenDefined() throws Exception {
    objectUnderTest.stop();
    verify(client, times(1)).disconnect();
}
```

When I run this, I obviously get a NPE on the `Future` object.  I cant think of any `when()` code that can successfully return me a mocked `Future` or anything like that.  How could I get this?

`MyServer` contains a `client` connector, that connects to an outside server upon initialisation of `MyServer`.  Multiple `MyServer`s can be created, each with their own channel to the outside server, through their `client`.  All of the instances of `MyServer` are maintained by a `MyServerRegistry`.  When a connection is no longer required, the `client` will disconnect, and the `MyServer` instance removed from the registry.

**Note! `client` is not Autowired into MyServer, but instead initalised and a connection opened in the constructor of `MyServer`.  I also have no control over the (non-final) `disconnect()` call returning a `Future<Void>`.**

Comment: you are not showing enough details.  Show how client is declared in the `MyClient` class.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. why would `when(client.disconnect).thenReturn(someFutreMock)` not work?

Comment: @Jonathan When I tried that IntelliJ tells me that it `Cannot resolve the method thenReturn(java.util.concurrent.Future)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the simple:

```
when(client.disconnect()).thenReturn(mockedFuture);
```

Or am I overlooking something here? You can verify the method call, so why do you think you can't mock it?!

The `client` object is *your* object. You already mocked it. So what makes you think you don't have control over its `disconnect()` method? That method is called on your mock; it returns a value, so you can mock it!

( unless `MyClient` or `disconnect()` is final. then you need to use newer versions of Mockito 2 supporting "final-mocking" as experimental feature )

Comment: When I tried that IntelliJ tells me that it `Cannot resolve the method thenReturn(java.util.concurrent.Future)`

Comment: Then you have done something wrong. Put up a [mcve] then! Are you sure you got the brackets right `when( mock.method() ) . thenReturn () `?

Comment: Urgh, it was a very stupid mistake.  The Future returned is `io.netty.util.concurrent.Future`, I was mocking `java.util.concurrent.Future`.  The normal `when()...` syntax works fine now that U have fixed the import.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I appreciate your decision ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The `NullPointerException` is because the default behaviour of a mocked object is to return null.
Thus, the `disconnect()` method is returning null from the `client` mock.

Assuming that `client` is `@Autowired` in the `MyServer` class and that the
`disconnect()` method is neither static nor final (which seems to be the case),
you can mock the `client` object then define the behaviour of the `disconnect()` method.

Add this variable to your test:

```
@Mock
Future<Void> mockFuture;
```

Add this behaviour to the mock `client`

```
doReturn(mockFuture).when(client).disconnect();
```

Comment: Unfortunately `client` is not Autowired into `MyServer`.  Client connections are maintained in a `MyServerRegistry`, when the connection is made, allowing future calls to be made on each specific client.  So the clients are created for each individual instance of `MyServer`.  When they are done, the MyServer object is removed from the registry.

Comment: Mock the MyServerRegistry to return a mock client.

Comment: Urgh, it was a very stupid mistake.  The Future returned is `io.netty.util.concurrent.Future`, I was mocking `java.util.concurrent.Future`.  The normal `when()...` syntax works fine now that U have fixed the import.  Thanks for your help.